# Floating-point to integer division increases the precision but don't understand why

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I am going through a C application code and find that float by integer division increases the precision and I don't understand why.
E.g. dividing a floating point number 12926.0 by the integer 100 should result in 129.26, but instead I am getting the result 129.259995

Below is a simple code representation of the actual code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int i=12926;
    float k=0.0;

    k=(float) i / 100;

    printf("k <%f>\n",k);
}
```

I have searched for explanations and tried evaluating values and expressions while debugging in GDB -

```
(gdb) print 12926.0 / 100.0
$39 = 129.25999999999999
(gdb) print (float) i / 100
$40 = 129.259995
(gdb) print i / 100
$41 = 129
```

Flummoxed why C is showing the result as 129.259995 instead of 129.26. Is there a way to control the precision length to get 129.26 as the result?

Comment: What does your title mean? `k=(float) i / 100` in your program uses `float` division. `12926.0 / 100.0` in the debugger uses `double` division. ` (float) i / 100` in the debugger uses `float` division. It uses an integer divisor (that is converted to `float` to match the numerator), but the result is not more accurate, and is not shown with more precision, than the `double` operation. `i / 100` uses integer division, and its result is not more accurate than the floating-point operations. What do you mean that “Floating-point to integer division increases the precision”?

Comment: @user3363546, "dividing a floating point number 12926.0 by the integer 100 should result in 129.26" is incorrect.  `float` typically can encode exactly nearly 2^32 different values.  `129.26` is **not** one of them.  The closest `float` is exactly 129.2599945068359375.  Printing that to 6 places after the `.` is 129.259995.

Answer (score 1):

From `printf()`'s man page:

> f, F   The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal
> notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of
> digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the
> precision specification.  **If the precision is missing, it
> is taken as 6**; if the precision is explicitly zero, no
> decimal-point character appears.  If a decimal point
> appears, at least one digit appears before it.

---

> Is there a way to control the precision length to get 129.26 as the
> result?

Yes, specify precision:

```
printf("k <%.2f>\n",k);
```

Comment: Thanks Haris, that does answer my 2nd question. However, when the precision is not specified why is the result 129.259995 and not 129.260000?

Comment: See the duplicated answer.